# Application Unfortunately stopped when going from 2nd activity to 3rd activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I'm new to Android developing. This is an assignment which was given to me. I have to convert the value and the converted value must be shown in the next activity. But when I press the submit button its crashes.I don;t know what is the problem. Is there a problem with my RadioButtons. Please help me...

This is the second activity(ConvertActivity)

```
package com.gihan.temperatureconverter;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;




public class ConvertActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//RadioButton cel=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rCel);
//RadioButton fah=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rFah);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_convert, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void calculation(View view) {

    EditText val=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    int value = Integer.valueOf(val.getText().toString()).intValue();
    int ans=0;
    int fahval=0;
    int celval=0;

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.rCel:
            if (checked){
                ans=((value-32)*5/9);
                fahval=value;
                celval=ans;}
            break;
        case R.id.rFah:
            if (checked){
                ans=((value*9)/5)+32;
                celval=value;
                fahval=ans;}
            break;
    }


    /*if (cel.isChecked()){
        ans=((value-32)*5/9);
        fahval=value;
        celval=ans;
    }
    if (fah.isChecked()){
        ans=((value*9)/5)+32;
        celval=value;
        fahval=ans;
    }*/

    Intent intent = new Intent(ConvertActivity.this, LastActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("celval", getText(celval));
    intent.putExtra("fahval", getText(fahval));
    ConvertActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

This is the 2nd XML(activity_convert)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.gihan.temperatureconverter.ConvertActivity"
android:background="@drawable/ic_background">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:hint="Enter Value"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="To Celsius"
        android:id="@+id/rCel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffc80301"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="To Fahrenheit"
        android:id="@+id/rFah"
        android:checked="false"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffc80301"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rCel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rCel"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rCel" />

</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/sub"
    android:onClick="calculation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the 3rd activity(LastActivity)

```
package com.gihan.temperatureconverter;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class LastActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView vFah=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.vFah);
TextView vCel=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.vCel);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_last);//use whatever layout you want.

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int celval=extras.getInt("celval");
    int fahval=extras.getInt("fahval");
    //String cel=String.valueOf(celval);
    //String fah=String.valueOf(fahval);
    vCel.setText(Integer.toString(celval));
    vFah.setText(Integer.toString(fahval));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_convert, menu);
    return true;



}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void again(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LastActivity.this, ConvertActivity.class);
    LastActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}

public void home(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LastActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    LastActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

This is the 3rd XML(activity_last)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_background"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.gihan.temperatureconverter.LastActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Successfully Converted"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textColor="#ffff0004"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Home"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:onClick="home"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate again"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:onClick="again"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Fahrenheit"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textColor="#ff0010ff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Celsius"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:textColor="#ff0010ff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/vFah"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ff9300ff"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/vCel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ff9300ff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gihan.temperatureconverter" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ConvertActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LastActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
 --------- beginning of crash
06-09 21:05:58.413    2381-2381/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gihan.temperatureconverter, PID: 2381
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton
        at com.gihan.temperatureconverter.ConvertActivity.calculation(ConvertActivity.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Some Comments were some ways I tried. It's also failed.
And also this is Android Studio Project.

Comment: What is error? How are you opening 3rd activity? What is use of  `calculation` method of second activity?

Comment: Have you added your second activity on the manifest.xml?

Comment: when i press the submit button it's unfortunately stopped. It doesn't open the 3rd activity.  I used 'calculation' method to convert the temperature. Is there a problem?

Comment: Yes. I did. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Error Solved Check this code

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     EditText val;

       public static int ans;
       public static String fahval="";
       public static String celval="";

        RadioButton Box1,Box2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        val =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);   
    }



        public void calculation(View v)
        {


          //get value from edit text box and convert into double
          double a=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(val.getText()));

            Box1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rCel);
            Box2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rFah);


          //check which radio button is checked
          if(Box1.isChecked())
          {

          //display conversion

         celval = String.valueOf(f2c(a));
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), celval,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Box1.setChecked(true);
          }
          else
          {
                fahval = String.valueOf(c2f(a));
            //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fahval,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Box2.setChecked(true);
          }


           Intent intent = new Intent(this, LastActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("celval", celval);
            intent.putExtra("fahval", fahval);

          startActivity(intent);

        } 


       //Celcius to Fahrenhiet method 
       private double c2f(double c)
       {
             return (c*9)/5+32;
       }
       //Fahrenhiet to Celcius method
       private double f2c(double f)
       {
             return (f-32)*5/9;
       }  


    }
```

LastActivity.java

```
public class LastActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView vFah;
    TextView vCel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.last);//use whatever layout you want.

        vFah=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.vFah);
        vCel=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.vCel);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String  celval=extras.getString("celval");
        String fahval=extras.getString("fahval");
        //String cel=String.valueOf(celval);
        //String fah=String.valueOf(fahval);
        vCel.setText(celval);
        vFah.setText(fahval);

    }



    public void again(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LastActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        LastActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void home(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LastActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        LastActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I add the Orientation property. Now after clicking submit button emulator reboots.

Comment: while crashing you will get some error message in logcat that i need

Comment: above code is working, its solved your problem accept the answer. it may help to others

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Could you please tell me how did you find the problem and solve it???

Comment: you are not properly declared the textview and edittext, then i had changed, also i have changed the faren value as string

Comment: in your code add validation for edittext will not be empty.else it may crash

Comment: vote up the answer ;) , when your are getting the valid reputaton

Comment: thank you very much bro. Now I got it. I can't vote up answers yet. I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was building some apps this week, and couldn't figure out why I couldn't navigate from the Main Activity to a second activity and from there to a 3rd level activity (that would pop to 2nd activity), and app kept crashing when I added the 3rd. Finally looked in the Logcat to figure out what's wrong, and then read "Cannot Navigate from 'second activity'.... This View will not accept Navigation". Searched through code to find errors, but Never thought to look there before.